# Filtering data based on timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, informatica-powercenter

I have developed a informatica flow, that basically would read a very big table (say about 120-300 million records)from SQL Server and load it into another database.
The filtering criteria would be a datetime2 field(of when the record was inserted into the table).

Before and after reading, i would be creating and dropping a non-clustered index on this timestamp field. Due to shortage of time, i couldnt actually do a performance testing.

Do you think that with the non-clustered index in place, filtering based on a timestamp field is ok? I mean a very rough idea on how the performance would be? I do not want the performance to be hit too badly!

Comment: It's anyone's guess. Maybe creating the index actually takes more time than importing your data would. Your first performance test should come up right when you first try to import, no?

Comment: "Due to shortage of time, i couldnt actually do a performance testing."  You'll just be doing your performance testing in production.

Comment: Well, Actually we do not have that great data in the test environment, So i could just run a few imports, but not on the actual volume. I guess i will have to run a test and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the NCI means reading the entire table.  So if you create it each time you need to run this query, you'll be worse off.  how often will you be using the informatica flow?  If the frequency means the index is worth it, make the index permanent.

Comment: The flow is really an adhoc one, and it mostly is going to be used somewhere like yearly once, and hence its very rarely used. And also, i cannot keep it permanently, as this table is incremental loaded (inserted and updated) every day basis. Since the frequency of load is very rare, and also since the table would be updated constantly, i decided to go with creating and dropping the index.

Comment: then forget about indexing,  it won't help you

Comment: But just to add, when this flow is going to be used(even if its once in a year), at that particular point in time, the data updates is going to be stopped on this table. So is that index not going to help, since the updates are stopped?

Comment: the thing is, it takes as long to build the index as to read the whole table.  so building an index, running your job, then dropping the index will be worse, overall, then not building the index at all

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for the helpful answer. I will definitely have to do some performance tests, before taking this step then.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add, that that number of records are 100 million. and index creation took just 2.5 minutes on a timestamp field!!!

and i am now trying to load records based on timestamp, say records that were loaded last 4-5 days, and its really a very nice solution for me, it works as intended.